# Computing an average, I need to write a single statement that assigns avg_sales with the average of num_sales1

Tags: python

I need to write a single statement that assigns avg_sales with the average of num_sales1, num_sales2, and num_sales3, Sample output with inputs: 3 4 8, Average sales: 5.00.

Comment: please give more context, sample input/output and also what you have tried

Comment: `sum([3,4,8])/len([3,4,8])` . Also, please read this . https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

try numpy:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.average([3, 4, 8]))
```

output:

```
5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It says a single statement so

```py
avg_sales = float((num_sales1 + num_sales2 + num_sales3) / 3)
```